# Reconfiguring grid columns in ExtJs4 - SelModel disappears?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am defining a grid which has a `selModel`.
Each time the store loads, the grids columns are dynamically reconfigured using the grids [Reconfigure](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.grid.Panel-method-reconfigure) method.
However when I do this the grids `selModel` disappears.
How can I reconfigure the grids columns to also include the selModel.
Below is some example code:

```
//The Selection Model for the grid.
var sm = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel();

//The Grid
var grid = new Ext.grid.Panel({
    store: store,
    selModel: sm,
    columns:[{
            header: 'Loading ...'
        }]
 });

//The store on load event where the columns are reconfigured
store.on('load', function(store){
    var columns = store.data.Data.items;
    grid.reconfigure(store, columns);
}, this);
```

In ExtJs3 I could specify the selModel as a column itself but this is not the case in ExtJs4. So how can I ensure the selModel is always visible even after reconfiguring the grids columns?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue. Sencha forum got some replies, but didn't work for me at least: http://goo.gl/b0DyG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug which is reported in Extjs version [4.0.2]. Now, it has resolved in Extjs version [4.0.7].

Comment: Are you sure it's resolved?  I'm on 4.0.7 and now I get a double checkbox column when I do a reconfigure w/ a selection model attached.

Answer (score 0):

From the 3.3.1 API docs (my emphasis):

> Reconfigures the grid to use a
>   different Store and Column Model and
>   fires the 'reconfigure' event. The
>   View will be bound to the new objects
>   and refreshed. **Be aware that upon
>   reconfiguring a GridPanel, certain
>   existing settings may become
>   invalidated.** For example the
>   configured autoExpandColumn may no
>   longer exist in the new ColumnModel.
>   Also, an existing PagingToolbar will
>   still be bound to the old Store, and
>   will need rebinding. Any plugins might
>   also need reconfiguring with the new
>   data.

I believe you just need to re-set the SelectionModel after you reconfigure your grid.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any idea on how I can reset the SelectionModel then?