# How to dynamically set the grids CheckBox Selection Model in ExtJs4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid, extjs4

This leads on from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6277991/reconfiguring-grid-columns-in-extjs4-selmodel-disappears).
I initialize a grid with a CheckBox Selection Model, however when I reconfigure the grid the Check Box Selection Model visaully dissapears.
What I want to do is dynamically add a CheckBox Selection Model to a grid after reconfiguring the grids columns, and visually display it.

I have tried something like this:

```
var sm = new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel();
grid.selModel = sm;
grid.doLayout();
```

Comment: Hi shane87, did you find a solution for this issue? How did you solve that?

Comment: Hi @hienvd it seems that this was a bug which has been fixed according to Marc Abbey's answer below

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. SelectionModel dynamic flag

```
//dynamically change, true or false, as the case 
selectionModel = true

var sm = {} // Selection Model

if (selectionModel){
    sm = Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel')
}

var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selModel: sm,         
    frame: true,
    store: store,
    columns: columns,
    // more code ....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ExtJS4, just do a `grid.getSelectionModel()` after your reconfiguration and see if it works. 
You don't have to *do* anything with the returned value. (if it doesn't work, debug to see what is returned by this method. is it an instance of `CheckboxModel`?)

Comment: Thanks. Yes it returns an instance of the CkeckboxModel. i need some sort of way to redisplay it?

Comment: I was thinking grid.getSelectionModel() would reconfigure the selModel before returning it. Does it not? (you need to call it after you do your reconfiguration)

Comment: Thanks for your response. But that didn't work..any other ideas? Im really stuck on this one :(

Answer (score 0):

Note that this was a bug that has recently been patched:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?238825-Checkbox-disappears-after-reconfigure-call-on-locked-grid-with-checkbox-selection-mod